# Structures portions as argument: unknown type name

Tags: c, function, structure

I'm trying to pass in structure portions as arguments. However, I'm getting the following message on compilation: "unknown type name 'time1'". Here's the section of my code that's causing these problems:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct time {
    int hour;
    int minutes;
    int seconds;
};

struct time time1;
struct time time2;
struct time elapsed;

int hourDif (time1.hour, time2.hour) {
    if (time2.hour >= time1.hour) {
        elapsed.hour = time2.hour - time1.hour;
    }
    else {
        elapsed.hour = 24 - (time1.hour - time2.hour);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Function definitions need a type and a name for each argument. You've given neither--you've given actual data, like you're calling the function rather than defining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
int hourDif (time1.hour, time2.hour)
```

is not a function call, it's a function declaration and in your case it's also it's definition, what you need is

```
int hourDif (struct time time1, struct time time2)
 {
    int difference;
    difference = 0; /* some compilers might complain */
    if (time2.hour >= time1.hour)
        difference = time2.hour - time1.hour;
    else
        difference = 24 - (time1.hour - time2.hour);
    return difference;
}
```

and then somewhere in the code, without the need for global variables you would have

```
struct time time1;
struct time time2;

/* initialize `time1' and `time2' */
int difference  = hourDiff(time1, time2);
```